# R.Net: Sourcing/Parsing a Script.R file Stored as Text File in Visual Studio (C#) Property Resources

Tags: c#, r, visual-studio, r.net

I have a R script file, let's call it "Script.R," that I want to source into R from C# (using R.Net). For example, Script.R has several functions in it that I want to call from C#/R.Net.

For deployment purposes, I have added Script.R as a "Resource" in Visual Studio's "Properties." At run time I can get the text of the Script.R file as a C# String by using the "MyProject.Resources.Script" (where it is assumed that the project is called "MyProject" and the Script.R resource is named with the field "Script.")

Now, I know I can use R's "source" function, as called from R.Net, with the file path of the Script.R, e.g.,

```
rEngine.Evaluate(String.Format("source('{0}')", filePath));
```

... but, what I am trying to do (and can't seem to figure out) is how to source (or parse?) the Script.R from the MyProject.Resources.Script C# string. That is, I'd like to source my Script.R from the resource C# string rather than from a file.

Any idea how to do this?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I am having trouble sourcing from a file. WHat does your "filePath" look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so after thinking through how to combine C#/R.Net/R, I found a solution. Here's a broken out solution (using many more variables than need be, but hopefully providing more clarity):

```
String script = MyProject.Resources.Script; 
string[] scriptSplit = script.Split(new string[]{"\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
SymbolicExpression rscriptSplitSymbolicExpression = rEngine.CreateCharacterVector(scriptSplit);
rEngine.SetSymbol("rscriptSplitSymbolicExpression", rscriptSplitSymbolicExpression);
rEngine.Evaluate("eval(parse(text=rscriptSplitSymbolicExpression))");
```

Of course, this can be simplified to:

```
rEngine.SetSymbol("rscriptSplitSymbolicExpression", rEngine.CreateCharacterVector(MyProject.Resources.Script.Split(new string[]{"\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
rEngine.Evaluate("eval(parse(text=rscriptSplitSymbolicExpression))");
```

If you have a different way of doing it, I'd love to see your solution, too! Thanks!